# Cannot update an object more than once

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to write a function that will update products freely.
But in the second update I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [guru.springframework.domain.Product#4]
```

the code in the **controller**:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Update a product")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Product>> updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
       return productService.updateProduct(product);
    }
```

the code in the **ServiceImpl**:

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Product>> updateProduct(Product product) {
        boolean exist=productRepository.existsById(product.getProductId());
        if(exist){
            productRepository.save(product);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(productEntityFactory.toModel(product));
        }else {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("There is no product with the given ID, so it can't be updated");
        }
    }
```

if the sent json does not undergo any change, then you can send it as many as you want, but if there is a change, it will only work for the first time.

Comment: Do you believe this can help you? https://coderanch.com/t/648941/databases/org-hibernate-StaleObjectStateException

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush your change. Because otherwise you leave the change from the first request 'open'.
Just use `productRepository.saveAndFlush(product);`
Instead of `productRepository.save(product);`

This should work

Comment: It did not help unfortunately,still for the second time the server returns:{
    "timestamp": 1655624307635,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/product/update/"
}
and in the log:
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [guru.springframework.domain.Product#1]